# Mobile dropdown menu: part is hidden behind other div : using z-index doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu

I try to create a so called "hamburger menu" for my mobile website. The only issue that I have with the below code is when I click on the button, only a part of the navigation menu is visible and the rest of it is hidden behind the `div id="topnav-mobile"`.

I thought it would work using a z-index but apparently I'm doing something wrong.
What should I add or remove to the below code to make this work?

**Html:**

```
<div id="upper">    
    <div class="upper-mobile">
        <div class="upper-mobile-logo">
            <div class="mobile-nav">
                <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
                <div></div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="responsive-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Object 1</li>
                        <li>Object 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="upper-mobile-name">
            <img src="/images/logo-large.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="topnav-mobile">         
    <div id="topnav-left-mobile">
        <div class="topnav-left-mobile-title">
            <a class="topnav-left-mobile-link" href="/"><b>HOME</b></a>
        </div>
        <div class="topnav-left-mobile-title">
            <a class="topnav-left-mobile-link" href="/nav2"><b>Nav2</b></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#upper  { width:100%; height:auto; float:left; overflow:inherit; position:relative; }

.upper-mobile   { display:inherit; width:100%; float:left; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.upper-mobile-logo      { float:left; position:absolute; }
.upper-mobile-logo img  { float:left; position:relative; }
.upper-mobile-name      { float:left; }
.upper-mobile-name img  { position:relative; text-align:center; }

.menu-btn div   { position:absolute; left:100%; top:64%; padding-right:8px; margin-top:-0.50em; line-height:1.2; font-size:18px; font-weight:200; vertical-align:middle; z-index:99; }
.menu-btn span  { display:block; width:19px; height:3px; margin:4px 0; background:#F00; z-index:99; }
.responsive-menu{ display:none; position:relative; z-index:101; }
.expand         { display:block !important; position:relative; z-index:101; }

#topnav-mobile      { display:inherit; width:100%; float:left; position:relative; z-index:-1; }
#topnav-left-mobile     { display:inherit; width:100%; float:left; position:relative; z-index:-1;}
#topnav-left-mobile a:link  { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
#topnav-left-mobile a:visited   { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
#topnav-left-mobile a:hover     { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
#topnav-left-mobile a:active    { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
#topnav-left-mobile a:focus     { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
.topnav-left-mobile-title       { position:relative; z-index:-1;}
.topnav-left-mobile-link        { display:block; position:relative; z-index:-1;}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
         $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
         $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
         })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: z-index only works (a) if you position the element and (b) relative to an element's siblings (["stacking context"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index))

Comment: But isn't that exactly what I did...?

Comment: @NicholasYoung I made a JSFiddle... but that doesn't help much, does it? http://jsfiddle.net/hq160xx2/2/

Comment: @Stan it would help if you picked jquery as a script :) http://jsfiddle.net/hq160xx2/4/

Comment: @NicholasYoung Sorry, first time I'm using JSFiddle... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.upper-mobile {
    display: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px; // You need to add a height, your code is all over the place
}
```

Your upper-mobile wasn't high enough to show all of your elements. I added some height to get it to show. Your code is a bit all over the place so my suggestion would be cleaning it up and slimming it down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nicholas, but changing the height isn't what I was looking for. Let's say I want to give the "upper-mobile" class a height of 50px but at the same time I'd like that "Object 1" and "Object 2" should appear on top of the "home" and "Nav2" buttons...